# PHPでpingの疎通確認ができるフォームを作りたい

Tags: php, html

[pingチェックテスト](https://www.cman.jp/network/support/ping.html) の簡易版を作りたいのですが、やり方を調べてもコード内にIPアドレスを直接コードに書きこんで疎通確認するやり方ばかりで、入力フォームで打ち込んだIPアドレスの疎通確認する方法が分かりません。

ここにIPaddressを入力、checkボタンを押したときに下に成功した場合は結果を表示して失敗した場合はエラー内容を表示するという感じでやりたい。現在のコードも載せときます。

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PinPin</title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Ping Check</h1>
    <?php
    print "IP address<br>\n";
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" size="30" name="ipaddress" placeholder="8.8.8.8"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="check">
    </form>

    <?php
    
    $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
    echo exec("ping -n 1");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IPアドレスを入力してcheckボタンを押したときにその下に結果を表示したいです。

Comment: `ping` を発行する主体は Web UA 側？　それとも Web Server 側？

Comment: 勉強不足で質問の意味があまり分からないです...
私がやりたい事としては、コマンドプロンプトでpingコマンドを使った疎通確認をWeb上で行いたい感じです。

Comment: どことどこ間の疎通が知りたいですか？　あなたの操作しているPCと入力した IP アドレス間？　あなたが作った PHP ファイルが置いてあるサーバーと入力した IP アドレス間？　リンク先も後者であると明記されていますよね。

Comment: すみません、後者です！

Comment: 一見すると問題なさそうに見えますが、現状のコードで何に困っているかをもう少し具体的に説明してみてください。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません;
echo exec("ping -n 1")
のとこ現状IPアドレスを指定してなくて、コードの中に("ping -n 1 127.0.0.1")と直接書かないといけない状態なんです。私がしたいのはそうじゃなくて、Web側でIPアドレスを入力し、checkボタンを押したら下に結果を表示したいんです。@cubick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pingのパラメータを指定するには、. で文字列をつなぎます。
また、empty関数で値の存在をチェックすると良いでしょう
更に、$_POST["ipaddress"]の値がアドレスだけかチェックした方が良いと思います。

```
if(!empty($_POST["ipaddress"])){
  $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
  echo exec("ping -n 1 ".$ipaddress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

フォーム入力でIPアドレスは受け取っているので、

```php
    $ipaddress = $_POST["ipaddress"];
```

(exec経由で) ping の引数に IP アドレスを指定するだけのように思います。

**修正例:**

```
    echo exec("ping -n 1 $ipaddress");
```

余談として、exec コマンドを使うのであれば、不正な入力を受け取らないよう気をつける必要があると思います。